# Simulate discrete state space model with a for loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I need some help with simulating a discrete state space model. I have succeeded to simulate a time continuous state space model via matlab/octave code.

$$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)+ Bu(t)\\ y(t) = Cx(t)+Du(t) \\ x(t) = x(t) + \dot{x}(t) \Delta t(t) $$

But how would the update of state $x(t)$ and input $u(t)$ be if the for loop is discrete?

First of all, I have the discrete A and B matrices.

Comment: First of all this proposed numerical integration scheme is one of the simplest, but also one of the worst in therms of accuracy. Namely you would need much smaller time steps with this method to get the same accuracy as for example 4th order Runge-Kutta. But for discrete systems you do not have this problem, since by definition you already have a given step/update rule.

Comment: @Kwinvanderveen so you mean that I should change my numerical method and use runge-kutta insted?  I don't think I need that because matlab step function give the same result as my for loop. Only time continuous.

Comment: if you use a bigger time step size then you will see that difference will become more apparent. Also a commonly used method in matlab/octave is ode45, which uses an adaptive time step Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: But the problem with ode45 is because ode45 has not insignal.

Comment: If you have a known $u(t)$ and/or feedback law then it will be possible to formulate it in a way that ode45 can handle: $\dot{x}=f(t,x)$.

Comment: Yes I Know $u(t)$ but it's is not possible to have that as input for the ode45 function.

Comment: You can construct a function for the $f(t,x)$ in which you explicitly use your definition of $u(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Continuous state-space representation:
$$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)+ Bu(t)\\ y(t) = Cx(t)+Du(t)$$

Discrete state-space representation:
$$x(k+1) = A_dx(k)+ B_du(k)\\ y(k) = C_dx(k)+D_du(k)$$

It should be straightforward to calculate your state vector by using your initial conditions.